# TFS 2010 merge not picking up changes?

Tags: tfs, merge

Wondering what I am doing wrong... 
Created a new folder in windows explorer called Dev. Added it into TFS 2010 via PowerTools. Checked in to TFS. Converted it to a branch called Dev. Copied that Dev folder in windows explorer as Test. Added it via powertools to TFS.  Checked in. Converted it to a branch with Dev as the parent 
eg.

```
Dev
 |
Test
```

Copied Test in Windows Explorer as Accp. Added via PowerTools. Checked in.
Converted to Branch with Test as the Parent.

```
Dev
 |
Test
 |
Accp
```

Did changes in Dev. checked in. Merged to Test. checked in. Now I want to merge those changes to Accp. However I have no changesets showing to merge any longer. My history shows the item is checked in. When I get latest from Test, the changes are there.

How can I get the changes now in Test into Accp without touching all the files?

What did i do wrong? My hierarchy shows as I displayed above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you should create your highest branch first (Accp), you should then branch that folder to Test and then branch Test to DEV, this will set up your hierachy and TFS will know which branches have parent > child relationships.

By the sound of your description you have created the folders in windows explorer and have then added them to TFS, therefore TFS has no information regarding the relationships between these folders / branches

Comment: Hmmm... so If i were to just rename my folder from Dev to Accp and Accp to Dev, would that resolve the issue? right now when I look at the hierarchy it shows Dev as 'highest' item. Should I just blow away all the branches and keep the ACCP and start the entire branch build process again?

Comment: when you open the merge window does it show that Test Can Merge both ways?

Comment: Hi. I think that was the issue. I setup my branches with Dev being the 'source' when I should have set accp as the source and branch from there. my small changeset test went through all the branches correctly with just merges along the way.